# Scrape nested html structure

Tags: html, r, web-scraping, rvest

I would like to scrape the data from [this site](http://www.alanwood.net/pesticides/class_fungicides.html), without losing the information from the nested structure. Consider the name `benodanil`, which not only belongs to `benzanilide fungicides`, but also to `anilide fungicides` and `amide fungicides`. It's not necessarily always 3 classes, but at least one and up to many. So, ideally, I'd want a data.frame that looks as such:

| name | class1 | class2 | class3 | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| benodanil | benzanilide fungicides | anilide fungicides | amide fungicides | NA |
| aureofungin | antibiotic fungicides | NA | NA | NA |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |  |

I can scrape the data, but can't wrap my head around how to handle the information in the nested structure. What I tried so far:

```r
require(rvest)

url = 'http://www.alanwood.net/pesticides/class_fungicides.html'

site = read_html(url)
# extract lists
li = html_nodes(site, 'li')
# extract unorder lists
ul = html_nodes(site, 'ul')

# loop idea
l = list()
for (i in seq_along(li)) {
  li1 = html_nodes(li[i], 'a')
  name = na.omit(unique(html_attr(li1, 'href')))
  clas = na.omit(unique(html_attr(li1, 'name')))
  
  l[[i]] = list(name = name,
                clas = clas)
}
```

An additional problem is, that some names occur more than one time, such as `bixafen`. Hence, I guess the job has to be done iteratively.

Answer (score 2):

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(rvest)

url = 'http://www.alanwood.net/pesticides/class_fungicides.html'

site = read_html(url)
a <- site %>% html_nodes('li ul a')

tibble(name = a %>% html_attr('href'), 
       class = a %>% html_attr('name')) %>%
  fill(class) %>%
  filter(!is.na(name)) %>%
  mutate(name = sub('\\.html', '', name)) %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  mutate(col = paste0('class', row_number())) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = col, values_from = class) %>%
  ungroup()

# A tibble: 189 x 4
#   name         class1                  class2                class3                     
#   <chr>        <chr>                   <chr>                 <chr>                      
# 1 benalaxyl    acylamino_acid_fungici… anilide_fungicides    NA                         
# 2 benalaxyl-m  acylamino_acid_fungici… anilide_fungicides    NA                         
# 3 furalaxyl    acylamino_acid_fungici… furanilide_fungicides NA                         
# 4 metalaxyl    acylamino_acid_fungici… anilide_fungicides    NA                         
# 5 metalaxyl-m  acylamino_acid_fungici… anilide_fungicides    NA                         
# 6 pefurazoate  acylamino_acid_fungici… NA                    NA                         
# 7 valifenalate acylamino_acid_fungici… NA                    NA                         
# 8 bixafen      anilide_fungicides      picolinamide_fungici… pyrazolecarboxamide_fungic…
# 9 boscalid     anilide_fungicides      NA                    NA                         
#10 carboxin     anilide_fungicides      NA                    NA                         
# … with 179 more rows
```

Extract `name` and `class` from the webpage, `fill` the `NA` values with the previous non-NA, drop rows with `NA` values and get the data in wide format.